# $\mathcal{L}_1 = \{\text{Strings with a 1 at a multiple of 3 from the front}\} $ and ...

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

$$\mathcal{L}_1 = \{\text{Strings with a 1 at a multiple of 3 from the front}\} $$ and $$\mathcal{L}_2 = \{\text{Strings with a 1 at a multiple of 3 from the end}\}$$

I need to design a DFA for these.

for $\mathcal{L}_1 $ I found the regular expression $\{0\cdot \{0,1\}\cdot\{0,1\}\}^*\cdot1\cdot\{0,1\}^*$

Since if the string starts with a 1 then it doesn't have to have another 1. It is already in the set of accepted strings ($0$th position is a multiple of $3$).

Then I have the dfa: 
[image]

for $\mathcal{L}_2$ I just reversed the regular expression for $\mathcal{L}_1$:

$\{0,1\}^*\cdot1\cdot\{\{0,1\}\cdot\{0,1\}\cdot0\}^*$

But I am unable to come up with a DFA to accept this regular expression, which is odd.

Edit:

So you would basically solve the language: {1 at a distance 3k and the total length is 3k +1 OR 1 at a distance 3k + 1 and the total length is 3k + 2 OR 1 at a distance 3k+2 and the total length is 3k} which is straightforward but a very large DFA: At most $12^3  = 1728$ states.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_1$ can terminate whenever you like once it meets the criteria.  $\mathcal{L}_2$ can only terminate every three spots after a 1.  Worse yet, you don't know "which 1" is the one that the one that will be a multiple of 3 from the end.  You will need a far more complex DFA to keep track of which states can be end states.

Comment: Have you tried creating a NFA (nondeterministic) for your reversed regular expression? You could then convert the NFA to a DFA.

Comment: The minimal DFA for $L_2$ has 8 states, which is still manageable by hand. Just use the approach suggested by @james-e-reid .